# Performing same operation on all columns of a DataFrame and build a new data using new columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I want to perform a similar operation on all columns of a DataFrame and later want to create a new DataFrame using modified columns. Example DataFrame and incomplete code is given below. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [10, 20, 30, 40], 'C': [100, 200, 300, 400]})
print(df)

for i in df:
    columns = df[i] - df[i].mean()
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns)
    print (df2)
```

Comment: tried `df.apply()`?

Comment: I just tried it now after your suggestion. It works perfectly fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

You may pass any function within `apply()`.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [10, 20, 30, 40], 'C': [100, 200, 300, 400]})
df.apply(lambda x: x - x.mean())

     A     B      C
0 -1.5 -15.0 -150.0
1 -0.5  -5.0  -50.0
2  0.5   5.0   50.0
3  1.5  15.0  150.0
```